# How to reverse eshell direction?

Tags: eshell

Ref: https://superuser.com/questions/209394/reversed-terminal-command-line-window

How to solve that ^ problem for eshell?

Such that, typing any command at the command prompt and pressing return, keeps the point on the same line, but sends the command output block down instead of up.

Answer (score 1):

I think that feature comes with [em-smart](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/eshell/em-smart.el).

Some basic setup is explained at [Mastering Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/complete-guide-mastering-eshell):

```
(require 'eshell)
(require 'em-smart)
(setq eshell-where-to-jump 'begin)
(setq eshell-review-quick-commands nil)
(setq eshell-smart-space-goes-to-end t)
```